# How can I output the code for my model into a word document without taking a screen shot?

Tags: netlogo

I want to include an example of my model code within my project report. I have tried taking a screenshot of my code but it is just too long to be legible. I am therefore wondering if it is possible to output an image of my model code  that has not been minimised or cut up into a word document for annotation?

Answer (score 2):

(I assume the reason you don't just copy and paste is that you want to preserve the colors?)

Use “Save as Applet” on the File menu. From the resulting HTML file, cut out the applet part and just keep the code part.

Direct support for "Save as HTML" is coming in NetLogo 6.0; see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/645.

Answer (score 1):

If Seth guessed wrong and you just need a monospace font, you can just copy (ctrl-A,ctrl-C) in the Code tab, paste into your Word document, and set the font to any monospace font (like Courier New).

If Seth guessed correctly and you want syntax highlighting, you can get the [Vim syntax file](https://econpy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/text/vimfiles/syntax/netlogo.vim), open your NetLogo file in Vim, select the code range, and then use Vim's TOhtml command.  You can then read this HTML file into your Word document.

Note that using Word for reports involving code is a terrible idea: the code will immediately be out of sync, as soon as you make further changes.  Instead, learn LaTeX use the `listings` package to read your code into your document.